# Issue with JS callback when selecting a bokeh datatable row

Tags: javascript, python, bokeh

I used a bokeh datatable in a simple report I had, which had the lines of:

```
source = ColumnDataSource(df)
callback = CustomJS(args=dict(callback_args), code="""some JS code""")
source.callback = callback
```

I had a simple JS code that would change some other datasources. Clicking on each row of the datatable would trigger it and it worked fine.

I upgraded bokeh to version 2.2.1

And now this code doesn't work anymore.

It seemed that for a datatable I might need to use something like:

```
source.js_on_change('value', callback)
```

or maybe:

```
source.js_on_change('start', callback)
```

But it doesn't work and the error I get is:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'connect' of undefined
at f.connect
at f._update_property_callbacks 
at f.connect_signals 
at Function._initialize_references_json
```

I wonder if I am doing something wrong or is it possible that it's a bug in bokeh?

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bug with Bokeh. Take a look at this issue: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/10345

Answer (score 0):

Not a bug. ColumnDataSource has neither a `start` property nor a `value` property. You can only add callback handlers for properties that exist. You probably want

```
source.selected.js_on_change('indices', ...)
```

Comment: doesnt work, nothing happens and the logs indicates:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indices' of undefined

Comment: You will need to post a complete minimal reproducer to be able to investigate or speculate more.